# Building a jQuery Mobile App using Moovweb, jQuery mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile-application, moovweb, tritium

I am building my mobile site using Moovweb SDK.

1. I would like to transform my mobile site into a jQuery Mobile Web App. 
   Is there a way to do this with Tritium language? 
   Are there any Tritium libraries that support jQuery Mobile?
2. Next, I would like to build a Phonegap app (iOS & Android) to add native features.
   How can I include mobile-platform specific application logic using Tritium?
   For e.g. On an iPhone, I want my app to support feature A, but on an Android phone, I want my app to support feature B.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this using Tritium and the Moovweb SDK. There are actually a couple tutorials specifically on these topics that will walk you through the basic code of setting this up.

1. https://console.moovweb.com/learn/tutorials/building_a_site/mobile_web_apps
2. https://console.moovweb.com/learn/tutorials/building_a_site/mobile_hybrid_apps